# pandas python inserting part of a column to a column based on conditions pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

i have a large dataset that i want to work with , but here i am using a mock dataset:

```
data = {'Block': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,1,1,1],
    'Concentration': [100, 100, 100, 33, 33, 33,  0,0,0],
    'Name' : ['A', 'A',  'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'PB', 'PB', 'PB'],
    'value': [86, 194, 452, 140, 285, 2011, 100, 111, 222 ]}

data = DataFrame(data)
```

looks like this:

```
In [12]: data
Out[12]: 
     Block  Concentration Name  value
0      1            100    A     86
1      1            100    A    194
2      1            100    A    452
3      1             33    A    140
4      1             33    A    285
5      1             33    A   2011
6      1              0   PB    100
7      1              0   PB    111
8      1              0   PB    222
```

**there are a total of 24 Blocks, 3 types of concentrations and 5  Names for each Block.**

i want for each block to add 3 new '0' concentrations for each Name other than the name 'PB', and then append the values from 'PB' to the newly added '0' concentrations.

for the mock dataset here the desired output would be:

```
In [13]: data2
Out[13]: 
      Block  Concentration Name  value
0       1            100    A     86
1       1            100    A    194
2       1            100    A    452
3       1             33    A    140
4       1             33    A    285
5       1             33    A   2011
6       1              0    A    100
7       1              0    A    111
8       1              0    A    222
9       1              0   PB    100
10      1              0   PB    111
11      1              0   PB    222
```

my code so far , im able to grab out only the 'PB' rows for each block:

```
def PBvalue(sgrp): 
    PBvalue = sgrp.loc[data['Name']=='PB'].copy()        
    return PBvalue
PBvalues = data.groupby(['Block', 'Concentration']).apply(PBvalue)
```

output:

```
In [30]: PBvalues
Out[30]: 
                            Block  Concentration Name  value
 Block Concentration                                    
   1     0             6      1              0   PB    100
                       7      1              0   PB    111
                       8      1              0   PB    222
```

Comment: Are the PB values consistent or varying for each block group?

Comment: @ EdChum 'PB' values are different for each block.

Comment: @Jessica Did you try anything at all, post the code too.

Comment: @WoodChopper yes please see my edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
# create the mock dataframe with 3 blocks

data1 = DataFrame({'Block': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
    'Concentration': [100, 100, 100, 33, 33, 33, 100, 100, 100, 33, 33, 33, 0,0,0],
    'Name' : ['A', 'A',  'A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B',  'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'PB', 'PB', 'PB'],
    'value': [86, 194, 452, 140, 285, 2011, 8, 19, 45, 14, 28, 201, 100, 111, 222 ]})


data2 = data1.copy(); data2.Block = 2
data3 = data1.copy(); data3.Block = 3

data = pd.concat([data1, data2, data3], axis=0)

def temp1(df):
    df_others = df[df.Name != 'PB']
    df_pb = df[df.Name == 'PB']
    def temp2(dfx):
        df_app = df_pb.copy()
        df_app = df_app[df_app.Concentration==0] # in case name 'PB' have more than one concentrations
        df_app['Name'] = dfx['Name'].values[0] ## modified code
        df_pername = pd.concat([dfx, df_app])
        return df_pername
    df1 = df_others.groupby('Name', group_keys=False).apply(temp2)
    df2 = pd.concat([df1, df_pb])
    return df2

data_changed = data.groupby('Block', group_keys=False).apply(temp1)

data_changed.index = range(len(data_changed))

In [151]: data_changed
Out[151]: 
    Block  Concentration Name  value
0       1            100    A     86
1       1            100    A    194
2       1            100    A    452
3       1             33    A    140
4       1             33    A    285
5       1             33    A   2011
6       1              0    A    100
7       1              0    A    111
8       1              0    A    222
9       1            100    B      8
10      1            100    B     19
11      1            100    B     45
12      1             33    B     14
13      1             33    B     28
14      1             33    B    201
15      1              0    B    100
16      1              0    B    111
17      1              0    B    222
18      1              0   PB    100
19      1              0   PB    111
20      1              0   PB    222
..    ...            ...  ...    ...
58      3              0    B    111
59      3              0    B    222
60      3              0   PB    100
61      3              0   PB    111
62      3              0   PB    222

[63 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: The first step is to read the data into a Pandas DataFrame. If the format of the dataframe is consistent with the example you gave above, then you can apply the function to the groupby object. It seems some error(s) come out of the reading procedure.

Comment: I modified the mock data, as well as the code, so the mock data have more than two names for the 'Name' column, and the code can handle it.

Comment: thank you! it worked even thought i did not use the `data2 = data1.copy(); data2.Block = 2  data3 = data1.copy(); data3.Block = 3`  piece of the code. what's the reason behind that?

Comment: just for making the mock data having more than one block, so that the code can handle multiple blocks.